# Proxy authorization not working with JettyConnectorProvider for Jersey 2.x(2.25.1)

Tags: rest, proxy, jersey, jersey-2.0, connector

I am trying to use JettyConnectorProvider with jersey 2.x for proxy support, but it seems that proxy authorization is not working, i have recently upgraded from Jersey 1.x to 2.x.

Please find below the code :

```
ClientBuilder clientBuilder= ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
final ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.connectorProvider(new JettyConnectorProvider());
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, proxyURI);
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_USERNAME, user);
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_PASSWORD, password);
clientBuilder.withConfig(config);
this.restClient = this.clientBuilder.build();
```

need help, please let me know if i am missing out something.

I can not use ApacheConnectorProvider as it has dependency on Apache HttpClient 4.x and this may require big changes for my system and this is a production issue.